# null callback in add_settings_section

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

Some code I'm looking at from a Plugin contains this line

```
add_settings_section("section", "Settings", null, "theme-options");
```

which has a `null` callback.

Having looked at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section
it says

> $callback - (string) (required) Function that fills the section with the desired content. The function should echo its output.

So, why is this `null` and what are the implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$callback = NULL` means there is the `$callback` variable but it has no the `value`.

In this case, unless you add any setting fields by `add_setting_field()` and register those settings by `register_setting()`, you'll get the `Settings` subheader on the `Settings` page without any content in this section.

[Here is an old tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-wordpress-theme-settings-page-with-the-settings-api/) which can be useful to show what I'm talking about. See the third screenshot and the code above it.

Also:

- [add_setting_field()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field)
- [register_setting()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting)
- [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)